# Rails - PostGIS + postgis_adapter Geometry Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, postgis

I use [postgis_adapter](https://github.com/nofxx/postgis_adapter) alongside with PostgreSQL 9.0.4, PostGIS 1.5.2 and Rails 3.1.0 on Ruby 1.9.2.
As described in the the postgis_adapter README, I tried to perform

```
Model.create(:geom => Point.from_x_y(10,20))
```

Postgres responds with

```
ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
HINT: You must specify a valid OGC WKT geometry type such as POINT, LINESTRING or POLYGON
```

The created GeoRuby Object looks like this:

```
#<GeoRuby::SimpleFeatures::Point:0x0000010420a620 @srid=4326, @with_z=false, @with_m=false, @y=20, @x=10, @z=0.0, @m=0.0>
```

Hopefully someone got an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Executive summary: it may work if you change it to:

`Model.create(:the_name_of_your_geo_column => Point.from_x_y(10,20))`

Longer version, with a high probability of Ruby howlers: I've barely written a word of rb but saw one too many great projects this week to continue in a state of ignorance. Working through the error messages in `irb` (starting from 0 in the language but very familiar with PostGIS):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter=>'postgresql',:database=>'moveable')

pt = TablePoint.new(:data => "Hello!",:geom => Point.from_x_y(1,2))
NameError: uninitialized constant Point
```

So, `require 'postgis_adapter'`, but then:

```
PGError: ERROR:  relation "table_points" does not exist
```

This must be that awesome naming convention in ActiveRecord that I've heard about. So create a table called `table_points` because I don't know what the database model/sync methods are.

```
moveable=> create table table_points(data text, geo_something geometry);
```

Notice here I used `geometry` rather than `geography` because my first instinct as to your problem was that the modeling methods in the database adapter layer created point types. Not at all, actually. Then again in `irb`,

```
pt = TablePoint.new(:geom => Point.from_x_y(1,2))
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: geom
```

No attribute named geom? Just to see what would happen, again in `psql`:

```
moveable=> alter table table_points add column geom geometry;
ALTER TABLE
```

Then:

```
irb(main):014:0> pt = TablePoint.new(:geom => Point.from_x_y(10,20))
=> #<TablePoint data: nil, geo_something: nil, geom: #<GeoRuby::SimpleFeatures::Point:0x1022555f0 @y=20, @with_m=false, @x=10, @m=0.0, @with_z=false, @z=0.0, @srid=-1>>
irb(main):015:0> pt.save
=> true
```

Unbelievable! What if I did:

```
pt = TablePoint.new(:data => 'is this even possible?', :geom => Point.from_x_y(38,121), :geo_something => Point.from_x_y(37,120))
=> #<TablePoint data: "is this even possible?", geo_something: #<GeoRuby::SimpleFeatures::Point:0x102041098 @y=120, @with_m=false, @x=37, @m=0.0, @with_z=false, @z=0.0, @srid=-1>, geom: #<GeoRuby::SimpleFeatures::Point:0x1020410c0 @y=121, @with_m=false, @x=38, @m=0.0, @with_z=false, @z=0.0, @srid=-1>>
irb(main):023:0> pt.save
=> true
```

Even more unbelievable!

```
moveable=> select * from table_points;
  data  |  geo_something  |  geom  
--------+-----------------+--------
        |                 | 0101000000000
        | 010100000000000 | 
        | 010100000000000 | 
...ble? | 00005E400000000 | 010000405E40
(4 rows)
```

I hesitate to post this as an answer because of fundamental lack of familiarity with Ruby but the above works (mindbendingly, to me), and you may be able to adapt it to your case.

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge of Rails and Ruby is very limited, but try instead:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
end

pt = Model.new(:geom => Point.from_x_y(10,20))

pt.save
```

Comment: `m = Model.new :attrs` + `m.save` actually is the same as `Model.create :attrs`

Comment: From my knowledge of PostGIS that error means that what is arrivng to the database is not a valid geometry. Does you interface work with PostgreSQL with having a geometry column?

Comment: @pex so, what happens (and it happened with me, having that error) is that what is arriving to PostGIS is not a valid geometry. I don't know how Ruby does it to insert a geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Spatial Reference System Identifier (SRID) fixed this problem for me:

```
Model.create(:geom => Point.from_x_y(10,20, 4326))
```

If you're using Google Maps, 4326 is the right SRID. Other maps and vendors might use something else.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem using [spatial_adapter](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter) when upgrading a working app from Rails-3.0 to 3.1.  It seems newer versions of ActiveRecord type cast your record to a GeoRuby object during insert. The [activerecord-postgis-adapter](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter) correctly handles the type cast of your geometry column (presumably to EWKT).  I spent a lot of time chasing this today and [Aaron Patterson's response in this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-core/KqAbPM675vE) was very helpful.

To fix your problem, upgrade your Gemfile and database.yml to use `activerecord-postgis-adapter`.